# public and source folders don't come in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, npx

react-app the command it won't work and it won't create the Public and the Source folder that is weird. I've tried many times and even with yarn it still won't work! Please tell me why this is happening thanks

Comment: which command you are using? and which version of create-react-app you have?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088

Comment: Can you add steps you followed to create this project?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your command line tool:

```
npx create-react-app test
```

It will create a React-App-template in a folder  called "test". It will include all the folders and features you are looking for.